# Fork and ignore child exit status

Tags: python, linux, posix

While currently writing a daemon which automatically updates multiple long running programs. I don't care about the program's exit status as the only way the child will exit is when force quitting them on upgrade. Unfortunately I'm creating a large number of zombie processes as a result.

I'm aware that I can use `waitpid(0, WNOHANG)` to listen for changes from any of the children (which is almost exactly what I want), however I'm also using the python multiprocessing module to run multiple separate upgrade processes in parallel, so the long running process which I could run `waitpid` from is actually the grandparent of the terminated process and therefore it never receives any signals.

So, is there any way to fork a child process so that I never need to check the exit status, or do I just have to deal with my process table being filled with zombies?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to control this with the setting of the signal handler for SIGCHLD.

In C, you would use:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

You'll need to adapt that to the Python interface.

You can use the Python 2 [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html?highlight=signal#signal) or Python 3 [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html?highlight=signal#module-signal) module; they seem to be identical for the problem on hand:

```
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

See: POSIX [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) for the underlying system behaviour (in particular, 'Signal Actions' and `SIG_IGN` under that section).

<sup>Warning: Python code not formally tested!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your process tree layout, it looks something like the following, where `parent1` and `parent2` are the things using Python's `multiprocessing.Process` objects.

```
grandparent
 |- parent1
   |- child1
   |- child2
 |- parent2
   | - child1
   | - child2
```

If that's the case, you'll want to be sure to call `multiprocessing.Process.join` from the parent processes (i.e., `parent1` and `parent2`) on their respective children. Once they terminate, regardless of reason, they will be cleaned up, which will allow `grandparent` to gracefully clean up `parent1` and `parent2`.

If you'd like to add additional logic to your parent to cycle through all of the children processes instead of blocking on the first one, you can use the `timeout` kwarg mentioned at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join to time out your join.