# How should I create new process / daemon in python for different requirements / scenarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have written a server which listens on certain port for incoming requests. When the request arrives, it forks a new daemon to handle each of those requests. I have currently used `multiprocessing` library for it as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mup
new_worker = mup.Process(target=worker,args=(param,))
new_worker.daemon = True
new_worker.start()
```

The issue is that, when I run `ps` command in bash, I find those daemon's are getting defunct status. Also parent process id PPID is not 1 (PID of intd) for these daemons. For example, following is the sample output of `ps` command:

```
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 28822  25898  28822  25898  |           \_ python3
 28823  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 28828  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
 28831  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
```

Note that process with PID 28822 is a server. Whereas processes with s {28823  ,28828,28831} are daemons. They are left back as `<defunct>`. Also note that these processes have `PPID=28822`, not `1`.

Also, notice the [multiprocessing doc says following](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

> Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

However when I do double forking using `os.fork()` <sup>[1](https://franklingu.github.io/programming/2016/03/01/creating-daemon-process-python-example-explanation/),[2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)</sup> and [handle `singnal.SIGCHLD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638179/1317018), it does not leave defunct processes and correctly assigns PPIDs of those daemons to 1. For example, following the output of `ps` command:

```
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
 43683      1  43682  43682 python3
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
 43683      1  43682  43682 python3
 43690      1  43689  43689 python3
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
 43683      1  43682  43682 python3
 43690      1  43689  43689 python3
 43699      1  43698  43698 python3
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
 43690      1  43689  43689 python3
 43699      1  43698  43698 python3
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
 43699      1  43698  43698 python3
$ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
   PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
 43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
```

Note that process with pid 43680 is a server. Whereas processes with pids {43683,43690,43699} are daemons. They are created and exit gracefully without leaving back as `<defunct>`. Also note that these processes have `PPID=1`.

Which approach should I prefer in my scenario?

**Update**

I am trying to understand which approach to use in which scenario / requirement.

Consider, slightly different requirement: what if I want server pre-create daemons (reading their count from some config) and then have server simply assign different incoming requests to different daemon (or put those requests to daemon's queue) currently free. In this scenario, does it makes sense to have daemon processes (as created with double forking using `os.fork`)?

And in initial requirement / scenario, does it makes sense to follow workers as created using `multiprocessing.Process()`?

Comment: Why do you want daemon process for handling requests ? You could create a pool of workers with `multiprocessing` and / or queues to pass requests to workers.

Comment: @rocksportrocker Actually I am trying to understand which approach to use in which requirement / scenario. For example consider slightly different requirement. What if I want server pre-create daemons (reading their count from some config) and then have server simply assign different incoming requests to different daemon (or put those requests to daemon's queue) currently free. In this scenario, does it makes sense to have daemon processes (as created with double forking using `os.fork()`) instead of workers created with `multiprocessing`?

Comment: This is a good question. Just for me, I think double fork is useful when you use Python as a launcher to launcher other service. For example, you need to do some checks and initialization, and you think Python is convenient to do this.

Comment: I would use a `Pool` from `multiprocessing` and use `apply_async` to do the work.

Comment: @rocksportrocker for both scenarios?

Comment: I don't get why you want to demonize the worker processes, I guess they should be shut down when the master process finishes, right ?

Comment: This is a second scenario explained in update. Its like if I am getting huge number of requests, then its better to have pre-spawned processes and forward the incoming processes to one of them (or put in queue of one of them, whichever is free at that time), instead of spawning processes as and when I receive the requests. This is to eliminate process creation and termination time, which could be very high when I receive huge number of requests and I fork a new process for each incoming request.